# Import AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I trying to build a jenkins pipeline that will deploy some common AWS resources and then will deploy the specific service resources.

Here is the common resources part, is being deployed with success.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    GoatfolioUserPool:
      Type: 'AWS::Cognito::UserPool'
      Properties:
        AccountRecoverySetting:
          RecoveryMechanisms:
            - Name: verified_email
              Priority: 1
        AutoVerifiedAttributes:
          - email
        EmailVerificationSubject: "GOATFOLIO - Verifique seu e-mail"
        Policies:
          PasswordPolicy:
            MinimumLength: 6
            RequireLowercase: true
            RequireNumbers: true
            RequireSymbols: true
            RequireUppercase: true
            TemporaryPasswordValidityDays: 1
        Schema:
          - AttributeDataType: String
            Name: email
            Required: true
          - AttributeDataType: String
            Name: given_name
            Required: true
        AliasAttributes:
          - email
        UsernameConfiguration:
          CaseSensitive: false
        UserPoolName: "goatfolio"

    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
          Properties:
        Name: ApiGatewayRestApi

    ApiGatewayAuthorizer:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties:
        AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 10
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        Name: GoatCognitoAuthorizer
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
        ProviderARNs:
          - {"Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:cognito-idp:", {Ref: "AWS::Region"}, ":", {Ref: "AWS::AccountId"}, ":userpool/goatfolio", Ref: GoatfolioUserPool]]}

  Outputs:
    ApiGatewayAuthorizerOutput:
      Value:
        Ref: ApiGatewayAuthorizer
      Export:
        Name: ${self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayAuthorizerOutput
```

The specific part:

```
functions:
  getConsolidated:
    handler: handlers.consolidate_investments_handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: portfolio/
          method: get
          authorizer:
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
            authorizerId:
              Ref: {'Fn::ImportValue': '${self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayAuthorizerOutput'}
```

I'm trying to use this ImportValue but it's giving this error:

> ```
> Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: every Ref object must have a single String value.
> ```

I've tried some other things as well, unsuccessfully.

There is a way to print the return of the ImportValue so I can understand what's happening?

I'm doing something terrible wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view export value of `'${self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayAuthorizerOutput'` in your stacks' console, in `Outputs` tab, or in CloudFormation console in `Exports` menu.

`!Ref` in your context can't be used, as the imported value is from other stack. If you just want to use imported value, then there is no need for `!Ref`.

You can try the following:

```
    authorizerId: {'Fn::ImportValue': '${self:provider.stage}-ApiGatewayAuthorizerOutput'}
```

Comment: Removing the !Ref it kinda worked, got some new erros to google for haha. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @VictorCorte No problem. If you get stuck with the new issues, you can always make new question on SO:-)